# Is it idiomatic "She is sitting with her hand / hands under the chin / the temple / the cheek", etc?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request, idioms, expressions

Look at these pictures & Is it idiomatic to say:

[image]

1- "**She is sitting with her hand under the temple / chick**" or "**She is sitting with her temple / cheek on the hand**"

[image]

2- "**He is sitting with his hands under the chin**" or "**He is sitting with his chin on his hands**"

[image]

3- "**She is sitting with her hand under the chin**" or "**She is sitting with her chin on the hand**"

[image]

4- "**They are lying with their hands behind their heads**" or "**They are lying with their heads on their hands**"

[image]

5- "**She is lying with her arms over / above the head**"

[image]

6- "**He is lying with his arm over / on the forehead**"

[image]
7- "**She is lying with her hand over / on the forehead**"

Comment: I'm not going to answer with the specific phrases you are looking for; but as a general pont, note that in English we usually use personal pronouns for body parts, so "under his chin", "behind her head" etc.

Comment: I would say No. 1 is 'leaning her cheek against her hand'. (A chick is a baby bird!)